# is there a way to get tags for a specific task ID using the azure CLI?

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-devops

I have just got the Azure fundamentals certificate, and I am practicing to improve my knowledge. Waht I am trying to figure out is a way for my build machine to run different tasks depending on the task associated to that commit. So basically the programmer will include in the commit message the task ID, and then I would need to look for the tags related to that task ID in the Azure DevOps task tracker (vsts) and depending on the tag/s run different tests on my jenkins pipeline. I have been checking the azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/devops?view=azure-cli-latest) but I am not able to find any command to get tags of a task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the ID of a task work item from the commit message, you can run the command '[**az boards work-item show**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/boards/work-item?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_devops_az_boards_work_item_show)' to get the details for this task work item.

```
az boards work-item show --id {work item id}
```

The response body of this command is a JSON type context. From the property '**`System.Tags`**' in the response body, you can get the tags that haven been added to this task work item.

You also run the API "[**Work Items - Get Work Item**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)" to get the same JSON type response body.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=6.1-preview.3
```

If you do not see the property '**`System.Tags`**' from the response body, add the parameter '**`expand`**' and set its value to '**`all`**' so that the response body can show the complete details for the work item.

- Using Azure CLI

  ```
  az boards work-item show --id {work item id} --expand all
  ```
- Using API

  ```
  GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?$expand=all&api-version=6.1-preview.3
  ```

By default, the parameter '**`expand`**' is set to '**`none`**', this may make some properties are not shown in the response body.